# How to write unit test for C# if else

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm new to unit testing, I want to know that how we can write unit test for if else.

```vb
Public Shared Function PrependIconForNonApprovedMessage(message As String, Optional title As String = "") As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim cb As New CBasePage
    If Not cb.IsUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled Then
        sb.AppendLine(HeaderUtils.RenderPageTitle(19, title, False, IconId:=String.Format("svg{0}Icon", title.Replace(" ", ""))))
    Else
        sb.AppendLine(HeaderUtils.RenderPageTitle(0, title, False, IconId:=String.Format("svg{0}Icon", title.Replace(" ", ""))))
    End If
    sb.AppendLine("<br/>")
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<div>{0}</div>", message))
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

How can I write unit test for the if else?

Comment: If you're asking how to test both the `if` and the `else` then you would do it with two separate tests. If that's not what you're asking, please explain better what you are asking.

Comment: Why is your question title about C# and your code in VB?

Comment: I'm working on an old project where I need to write tests in C# , aad code is written in VB.

Comment: I'd recommend reading more on this topic - The Art of Unit Testing: with examples in C# (book) is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test is written to test whether a code in separation of other concerns, or a "unit" works properly in a use-case.

When you have an if-else in your code, that seems to be two use-cases, so, by default one would implement a unit test where the if's block is set to be running and another one for the else.

Alternatively you can do multiple asserts into a single unit test, but you should avoid that in most cases and you should have a very good reason for mixing up multiple asserts in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we have to write test cases for all the kinds of return statements you have in your method, so if and else conditions have any return statement then only you need to write a test case for that.

you can check out this YouTube channel for a better understanding of the test case https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2cQw1DFz2k&t=120s

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there's an if/else structure in the code you're testing is an implementation detail. When writing unit tests you should be considering what the expected *behavior* is. Be careful not to focus too much on test coverage (which lines of code are hit), because in many cases the same line of code can have different behaviors depending on the input.

In your case, it looks like `CBasePage`'s `IsUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled` is a *state* that you're depending on. Ideally, you should refactor your code to make this part of your class's inputs. For example, you could have your class *inject* an interface that can provide this value. Or you could have your method require this value as one of its inputs:

```
Public Shared Function PrependIconForNonApprovedMessage(message As String, Optional title As String = "", Optional isUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    
    If Not isUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled Then
        sb.AppendLine(HeaderUtils.RenderPageTitle(19, title, False, IconId:=String.Format("svg{0}Icon", title.Replace(" ", ""))))
    Else
        sb.AppendLine(HeaderUtils.RenderPageTitle(0, title, False, IconId:=String.Format("svg{0}Icon", title.Replace(" ", ""))))
    End If
    
    sb.AppendLine("<br/>")
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<div>{0}</div>", message))
    
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Then you can write tests based on what output you'd expect to get from each of these inputs. Something like this:

```
    [TestCase("This is a test message", "TestTitle", false, "<h1>svgTestTitleIcon TestTitle</h1><br/><div>This is a test message</div>")]
    [TestCase("This is a test message", "TestTitle", true, "<h1>svgTestTitleIcon TestTitle</h1><br/><div>This is a test message</div>")]
    [TestCase("Another message", "AnotherTitle", false, "<h1>svgAnotherTitleIcon AnotherTitle</h1><br/><div>Another message</div>")]
    [TestCase("Another message", "AnotherTitle", true, "<h1>svgAnotherTitleIcon AnotherTitle</h1><br/><div>Another message</div>")]
    [TestCase("", "", false, "<h1>svg Icon</h1><br/><div></div>")]
    [TestCase("", "", true, "<h1>svg Icon</h1><br/><div></div>")]
    [TestCase("<script>alert('xss')</script>", "TestTitle", false, "&lt;script&gt;alert('xss')&lt;/script&gt;")]
    [TestCase("This is a test message", "<script>alert('xss')</script>", false, "&lt;script&gt;alert('xss')&lt;/script&gt;")]
    [TestCase("<script>alert('xss')</script>", "<script>alert('xss')</script>", false, "&lt;script&gt;alert('xss')&lt;/script&gt;")]
    public void TestPrependIconForNonApprovedMessage(string message, string title, bool isUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled, string expectedOutput)
    {
        // Act
        string result = YourClass.PrependIconForNonApprovedMessage(message, title, isUIProgressBarFeatureToggleEnabled);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, result);
    }
```